# TeamsLogon.aspx not passing subEntityId

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-online, spfx, microsoft-graph-teams

I have built a custom Teams app with a static tab pointing to a SharePoint page.

the code for the tab in the app manifest is

```
        "entityId": "mytab",
        "name": "My Static Tab",
        "contentUrl": "https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/sites/TARGETSITE/_layouts/15/TeamsLogon.aspx?SPFX=true&dest=https%3A%2F%2FTENANT.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2FTARGETSITE%2FSitePages%2FTARGETPAGE.aspx",
        "websiteUrl": "https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/sites/TARGETSITE/SitePages/TARGETPAGE.aspx",
        "scopes": [
            "personal"
        ]
```

All is working nice, authentication is done properly.

Now I want to perform some action on the page by deeplinking to the page with some parameter passed as subEntityId and reading the context's subEntityId in an SPFX webpart. According to
But unfortunately the value of `subEntityId` is always `undefined`.

The deep link would be

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/_?tenantId=e223420bb-edaf-792a-9dfd-961376a291ae#/apps/35cb66784-343b-4937-8980-9f38c47f737b/mytab?webUrl=https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/sites/TARGETSITE/SitePages/TARGETPAGE.aspx&context=%7B%22subEntityId%22:%20%22MY_PARAMETER_THAT_IS_NOT_PASSED%22%7D
```

Just linking to the static tab is working fine:

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/_?tenantId=e223420bb-edaf-792a-9dfd-961376a291ae#/apps/35cb66784-343b-4937-8980-9f38c47f737b/mytab
```

In both cases the tab is loaded and showing the SharePoint page, Teams-context is properly loaded, but subEntityId is always empty. How can I pass this parameter to my SPFx web part?

Comment: When you add sub-entity id in the deep-link you will receive the the value of subentity id in tabcontext. Could you please check [get context for tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context)?

Comment: Hi, subEntityId is already part of the context in deep link as you can see above. Or do I have to put it anywhere else? I have a static tab and no configurable tab where the value could be passed.

Comment: I worked on similar lines in past. Let me share what i tried: (1) I created an adpative card. I used deep Link to tab embed into below adaptive Card, which used into power automate to send notification, On click on button, it will navigate to Tab as well as pass parameterize url (2) then consume item id into SPFx webpart like this. SubEntityId used to get the parameterized value, assigned to provided variable: "public componentWillMount() {  
     
    microsoftTeams.getContext(teamsContext => {  
    this.itemId = teamsContext.subEntityId;  
    });  
  }  "

Comment: That’s pretty much what I need. But subEntityId is always empty. Could you share the urls you used? Both are in the app  manifest AND for the deep link containing the context/subEntityId?

Comment: Aaw, thats cool @ben. Let me check my code base and see what i can get for you.

Comment: That would be awesome

Comment: Step # 1: The deep link is different from the link provided by the copy link tab menu, its just generate deep link the points to tab. 

Step # 2: Sample Url will be generated like this,
 
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/a614643d-06d1-42cc-9166-25ad4e39f9d9/_djb2_msteams_prefix_1145688105?context=%7B%22subEntityId%22%3Anull%2C%22channelId%22%3A%22<<channel id>>%40thread.tacv2%22%7D&groupId=<<group id>>&tenantId=<<tenant id>>

Please note that Sub Entitiy Id can used to pass as parameterize value, if we need to simply navigate to tab, In that scenario it can be used as null.

Comment: Step 3: Deep Link to tab embed into my adaptive Card, it uses power automate to send notification. When we click button, it will navigate to tab as pass parameterized url too. Next one i will share the adapative cards action from the json:

Comment: "actions": [  
                {  
                    "type": "Action.OpenUrl",  
                    "title": "View Ticket",  
                    "url": "teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/a614643d-06d1-42cc-9166-25ad4e39f9d9/_djb2_msteams_prefix_1145688105?context=%7B%22subEntityId%22%3A@{triggerOutputs()?['body/ID']}%2C%22channelId%22%3A%2219%3A123c0abe7f0041c68066801eb8a0f8d2%40thread.tacv2%22%7D&groupId=e8312347-f8cd-4177-8661-88b335dab65b&tenantId=4cd94c60-104d-4a43-b441-e735fc34830b",  
                    "style": "positive"    }  
            ]

Comment: Step 4: Now we need use the item id into SPFx webpart:

microsoftTeams.initialize();
public componentWillMount() {  
     
    microsoftTeams.getContext(teamsContext => {  
    this.itemId = teamsContext.subEntityId;  
    });  
  }  

This way you can build a custom deep link to tab!!

Comment: Let me know if this helps or need help. Once you confirm i will move this to answer :)

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I'm doing here. I will double check the link an let u know the result.

Comment: No luck so far. Could you paste the url which you a using in the teams app's manifest for the static tab's contentUrl?

Comment: the url part in deeplink is a parameter and should be encoded somthing like this https%3A%2F%2FTENANT.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2FTARGETSITE%2FSitePages%2FTARGETPAGE.aspx%26context%3D%257B%2522subEntityId%2522%3A%2520%2522MY_PARAMETER_THAT_IS_NOT_PASSED%2522%257D

Comment: fully encode the webUrl value.

Comment: @ben - Are you still facing the issue? Could you please conform?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT I was able to fix it this week. I will write an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what fixed it:

Somehow the generated link including tenant_id is not working properly for deep links with subEntityId

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/_?tenantId=e223420bb-edaf-792a-9dfd-961376a291ae#/apps/35cb66784-343b-4937-8980-9f38c47f737b/mytab?webUrl=https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/sites/TARGETSITE/SitePages/TARGETPAGE.aspx&context=%7B%22subEntityId%22:%20%22MY_PARAMETER_THAT_IS_NOT_PASSED%22%7D
```

The following format did the trick an now MYCUSTOMPARAMETERVALUE is properly passed to subEntityId

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/06bc21a9-422f-4dd6-b32d-11820a242651/mytab?context=%7B%22subEntityId%22:%22MYCUSTOMPARAMETERVALUE%22%7D
```